# javascript: How to use ternary expression render in html?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, render-html

Here is a javascript ternary operator codes.

```
'<p>{balance>0?(Stock: {{balance}}):<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>}</p>'
```

I tried many ways in order to rendered proper in HTML, however has no luck.

Output: `{balance>0?(Stock: {{balance}}):<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>}`
Output expected: (Stock: 23)  or Not Available (in red color)

Thank you in advance!

Below is part of codes that use for working with Bloodhound plugin.

```
var prodName_typehead = {
                    name: 'prod_name',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    hint: (App.isRTL() ? false : true),
                    source: item.ttAdapter(),
                    limit: 20,
                    templates: {
                       suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
                            '<div class="media">',
                                  '<div class="pull-left">',
                                      '<div class="media-object">',
                                          '<img src="{{thumb}}" width="50" height="50"/>',
                                      '</div>',
                                  '</div>',
                                  '<div class="media-body">',
                                      '<p><strong>{{name}}</strong></p>',
                                      '<p>{{desc}}</p>',
                                       '<p>{balance>0?(Stock: {{balance}}):<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>}</p>',
                                  '</div>',
                            '</div>',
                          ].join(''))
                    }
                  };
```

Comment: use `` to write expressions.

Answer (score 2):

## I believe what you want is this:

```
`<p>${balance>0?`Stock: ${balance}`:`<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>`}</p>`
```

### When I run this:

```
balance = 0
`<p>${balance>0?`Stock: ${balance}`:`<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>`}</p>`
```

I get:

```
"<p><span class="text-danger">Not Available</span></p>"
```

### And when I run this:

```
balance = 1
`<p>${balance>0?`Stock: ${balance}`:`<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>`}</p>`
```

I get:

```
"<p>Stock: 1</p>"
```

I'm using javascript template literals to complete the variable substitution you were going for.

(Basically the issue you were having is that you needed ticks (`) instead of double quotes (") to make a template literal as NarayaN alluded to in his comment, a $ before the first bracket to start the javascript embed and then nesting this same logic for the balance inside the first string option.)

Comment: I tried with the method that you suggested but it does not work  -> 709 Uncaught ReferenceError: balance is not defined.

Comment: If the input of the `compile` step needs the double braces the correct solution should be:
`<p>${balance>0?`Stock: {{balance}}`:`<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>`}</p>`

Comment: error gone but still not working. The output show like this ${balance>0?Stock: {{balance}}:<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>}

Comment: @user610983 Sorry my previous comment might have been poorly formatted, can you confirm that you typed (ticks don't work here so replace the single quotes I write with ticks): '<p>${balance>0?'Stock: {{balance}}':'<span class="text-danger">Not Available</span>'}</p>'

Comment: Yes. I replaced the single quotes with ticks and add double braces. This time I got an error: unexpected string.